# Date picker does not expanded over parent div component

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I am using [vuexy](https://pixinvent.com/demo/vuexy-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/demo-1/extensions/datepicker) admin dashboard template in my Vue.js project and I am using the date picker component inside the collapse component provided by vuexy theme. when I click on date picker it should expand over the parent but it did not work as the following screenshot.

[image]

I tried to override the inner class of date pickers expandable component and make it to use `position: fixed;` then the expandable part is visible but it stays at the same position when we scroll as the following screenshot.

[image]

How can I fix this issue using CSS? (or even library-specific solution also acceptable)

Comment: it looks like z-index issue. try to increase value of z-index on vdp-datepicker class.

Comment: @DavorMlinaric I already tried that. It already has greater z-index than the parent.

Comment: other problem could be overflow hidden on some of parent objects.

Comment: @DavorMlinaric tried that too. did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the teleport attribute

```
<template>
    <VueDatePicker v-model="date" :teleport="true" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const date = ref(new Date());
</script>
```

[image]

[vue3datepicker.com/props/positioning/#teleport](https://vue3datepicker.com/props/positioning/#teleport)